# ASP.NET Odata multiple sub routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I'm trying to expose multiple databases through Odata Web API.
Now I want to divide each of my databases into a seperate sub url.
I already defined the necessary IEdm Models and Controllers.
The API is working as intended while I'm only using a single Odata Url.

My approach for using multiple sub urls is this:

```
    app.UseMvc(c =>
        {
            c.EnableDependencyInjection();
            c.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter().Count().MaxTop(null).SetTimeZoneInfo(timeZone);
            c.MapODataServiceRoute("Database1", "api/v1/Database1", Database1.GetModel());
            c.MapODataServiceRoute("Database2", "api/v1/Database2", Database2.GetModel());
        });
```

But when I'm trying to access the metadata for database 2 I'm getting `InvalidOperationException`, because some templates are only defined in the controller for database 1 and not in the controller for database 2.

My controller for database 1 looks like this:

```
    public class Database1Controller : ODataController
    {
        private Database1Context Context = new Database1Context();

        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute(DB1Entity1.ApiSubUrl)]
        public IQueryable<DB1Entity1> GetEntity1()
        {
            return Context.Entity1.AsQueryable();
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute(DB1Entity2.ApiSubUrl)]
        public IQueryable<DB1Entity2> GetEntity2()
        {
            return Context.Entity2.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

And my controller for database 2 looks like this:

```
    public class Database2Controller : ODataController
    {
        private Database2Context Context = new Database2Context();

        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute(DB2Entity1.ApiSubUrl)]
        public IQueryable<DB2Entity1> GetEntity1()
        {
            return Context.Entity1.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

I can access the metadata and all controller functions for the `api/v1/Database1` url, but can't access metadata or controller functions for `api/v1/Database2` url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for multiple sub urls is to limit the odata route verification of a controller method to the specific route.

So controller 1 would look like this:

```
public class Database1Controller : ODataController
{
    private Database1Context Context = new Database1Context();

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute(DB1Entity1.ApiSubUrl, RouteName = "Database1")]
    public IQueryable<DB1Entity1> GetEntity1()
    {
        return Context.Entity1.AsQueryable();
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute(DB1Entity2.ApiSubUrl, RouteName = "Database1")]
    public IQueryable<DB1Entity2> GetEntity2()
    {
        return Context.Entity2.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```